# How to highlight html text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to highlight html page text when I click on a button.

It is working when matching html page text not have any html tags. But it is not working when html page text have some tags (Like a, span, strong).

Long string 1 (Simple Text) => Workinh

Long String 2 (Simple Text) => Not

Long String 3 (Simple Text)

Long String 4 (Simple Text)

Html =>
bla bla....bla bla..
...bla bla Long string 1 (Simple Text "highlighted") ....
Long String 2 (Text with HTML Tags "not highlighted")....Long String 3 (Text with HTML Tags "not highlighted")....bla bla...Long String 4....

Ex:
**Case 1**

Input : I want to highlight html page text

Output: I want to highlight html page text

Page have => I want to highlight html page text

**Case 2**

Input : I want to highlight html page text

Output: not working

Page have => I want to **highlight** html page text

i.e. page have same string but have strong tag inside

any one help..??

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking any questions.

Comment: post your code, your question is not clear

Comment: Question Updated...

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="hilight">Hello</span>&nbsp;world
<button id="hilight">Hilight</button>

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#hilight").on('click', function() {
             $("span.hilight").addClass("your_css_class_to_change_background_color"); 
             //If you use bootstrap
             $("span .hilight").addClass("badge badge-info"); 
       });
   });
```

Comment: Searching a larger string (50-60 word) and html page have more than 1000 word

Answer (score 0):

you can perform jquery onclick function and add css to that text as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button").click(function(){
       $("p").css("background","yellow");
   });
});
```

see it once,you will get an idea.

Hope it helps for you.!! Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can make an id for your tags ex.

```
    <p id="test1"></p>               

    <script>
       $('#submit').on('click','function() {
           $('#test1').css("color", "red");
       });
    </script>
```

Other way you can set in css:

```
 p:focus {background: pink;}
```